# Passwordless login on Joomla 5

Tags: login, joomla-5.x, com-users

Is it possible to set up passwordless login on Joomla 5? This [excellent article](https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/december/passwordless-authentication-for-secure-fast-easy-logins-in-joomla-4) by Nicholas Dionysopoulos explains how to do it in Joomla 4. In that case,the user still had to enter his/her username.

In Joomla 5 it seems to be a bit different. I have enabled fingerprint login from a browser using the "Multi-factor Authentication - Passkeys" plugin, but that offers fingerprint login **in addition** to the username and password. What I am looking for is the ability to log in using **only** a fingerprint (i.e. no need to type anything from the keyboard).

This system is used by most of the banking apps that I know, and it is very convenient, especially on a mobile phone, where password managers aren't quite as easy to use as on a computer. Since it is used by banking apps, I presume that it's just as secure as a password login. I would like to implement such a system in Joomla.